# How to turn a list of strings to an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to code a program which when a user inputs some numbers it will reverse it it and display it on the page. I have to tried to use 'Object.assign', but it doesn't work for me. I have also tried '.toArray', but it still doesn't work(maybe my formatting is wrong?). I am just a beginner so go easy on me. Thanks for t. This is what i have so far:

[not working code but what i wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CVpE.png)

This works though:
[Working code but not what i wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM0of.png)

Comment: OK what you have tried so far that you are stuck at

Comment: "List of strings to array"  this doesn't make sense.

Comment: i have a bunch of strings in a list and i want to convert it to an array

Comment: please add your code in text form to the question. what does not work?

Comment: Sorry, its not letting me put my code in, i don't really know what's wrong. It looks alright to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: when I reread the question, I realized you wanted the array in reverse. Updated answer at the bottom.

press enter to add the input. If you don't want only numbers delete `type='number'`.

```js
var arr = [];
const input = document.getElementById('inpt');

input.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    arr[arr.length]=input.value;
    input.value="";
    console.log(arr);
  }
});
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter a number" type='number' id ='inpt'/>
```

```js
var arr = [];
const input = document.getElementById('inpt');
const output = document.getElementById('output');

input.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    arr[arr.length]=input.value;
    input.value="";
    var arr2= [...arr].reverse();
    output.innerHTML='';
    arr2.forEach(element => output.innerHTML+= element+' ');
    console.log(arr);
  }
});
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter a number" type='number' id ='inpt'/>
<div id = 'output'>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what .addEventListener does

Comment: `addEventListener` waits for a defined event to happen on a particular element. In this case the element is `<input placeholder="Enter a number" type='number' id ='inpt'/>`  and the event is the user pressing any key (`keydown`). Then we check if the key pressed is the enter key, and, if so, take the current value of the input element and add it to the `arr` array.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in a for loop

Comment: Yes I can tell you how to do it but first since I correctly answered the original question please mark it as correct (click the check mark)

Comment: sorry for not responding